# Check if not nil in Clojure

Tags: clojure

So I'm trying to use a 'some' to implement a recursive function. The way the function works is it returns either 'nil' or a vector of needed information. Then I want the 'some' function to return the first result of a bunch of recursive calls that isn't nil. The problem is that 'true?' returns false for a vector. I can't seem to find a function that distinguishes nil and vectors. Any help?

Comment: did you try `(nil? ....) ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a bit vague, but you can use the `nil?` function to test if a value is `nil`. You can use `(complement nil?)` as the first arg to `some` to return the first non-nil value in the coll

Comment: That doesn't work because 'nil?' returns true for both the 'nil' return value and the vector return value, so both are now true.

Comment: no, try it in the repl. nil? only returns true if its argument is nil.

Comment: you're right. I found my problem though: turns out 'some' gives back the return value of the pred and not the thing passed into it, as I was expecting. I used '#(if (vector? %) %)' as the pred instead. Thanks for your help anyways.

Answer (score 1):

identity

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/identity

```
(identity x)
```

Returns its argument.